# Are my streams protected while using Exoplayer?

Tags: android, exoplayer

I am using `ExoPlayer` to play my streams and I was wondering if `ExoPlayer` itself uses any sandbox to secure/protect the stream. If not, can you suggest any open source library to 'seal' my streams.